# ggplot2: Reverse order of chron dates

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a dataset vs. dates in ggplot2, with the y-axis being dates.  I'd like to have the dates in reverse chronological order.  With the earliest date at the top of the y-axis.  Plus I would like to format the date in a way that I want.

The trouble I'm having is that I believe that I need scale_y_continuous() and scale_y_reverse to accomplish this, but they do not play well together.  What I am trying in my plot is:

```
... ggplot setup ... +
scale_y_continuous(label=function(juldate) strftime(chron(juldate), "%Y-%m-%d")) +
scale_y_reverse()
```

The error I get is:

```
Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will replace the existing scale.
```

How can I get formatting and reversing to work together?  Note that in this example, the y-axis is a julian date integer, which is my last attempt to try to get things to work well together.

Independently, either scale_y... statement does what it should, either formatting correctly, or reversing the axis, but I can't use both.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Matt

ADDED: Reproducible example

```
 library("ggplot2")
 library("chron")


 # Data to graph.  Want to show a calendar, days on the left
 # and candle lines showing the duration of each event.
 work <- rbind(
             data.frame(ydate_start=15480, ydate_end=15489, event="Event One"),
             data.frame(ydate_start=15485, ydate_end=15499, event="Event Two")
             )


 # Formats nicely, but I want order of dates reversed
 ggplot(work,
        aes(x=event,
            y=ydate_start,
            ymin=ydate_start,
            ymax=ydate_end,
            color=event)
 ) +
     geom_linerange() +
     ylab("Date") +
     scale_y_continuous(label=function(x) strftime(chron(x), "%Y-%m-%d"))


 # Order reversed, but no formatting applied
 ggplot(work,
        aes(x=event,
            y=ydate_start,
            ymin=ydate_start,
            ymax=ydate_end,
            color=event)
 ) +
     geom_linerange() +
     ylab("Date") +
     scale_y_reverse()


 # Both delarations don't play well together well
 ggplot(work,
        aes(x=event,
            y=ydate_start,
            ymin=ydate_start,
            ymax=ydate_end,
            color=event)
 ) +
     geom_linerange() +
     ylab("Date") +
     scale_y_continuous(label=function(x) strftime(chron(x), "%Y-%m-%d")) +
     scale_y_reverse()
#> Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will replace the existing scale.
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem.  I must have had a typo or not tried this properly somehow, but the solution is that scale_y_reverse() takes 'label' as an argument, just like scale_y_continuous.  The following works:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("chron")


# Data to graph.  Want to show a calendar, days on the left
# and candle lines showing the duration of each event.
work <- rbind(
            data.frame(ydate_start=15480, ydate_end=15489, event="Event One"),
            data.frame(ydate_start=15485, ydate_end=15499, event="Event Two")
            )


# THIS SOLVES THE PROBLEM
ggplot(work,
       aes(x=event,
           y=ydate_start,
           ymin=ydate_start,
           ymax=ydate_end,
           color=event)
) +
    geom_linerange() +
    ylab("Date") +
    scale_y_reverse(label=function(x) strftime(chron(x), "%Y-%m-%d"))
```